# Dynatable callback function not working

Tags: jquery, dynatable

I'm trying to bind click event to `dynatable` generated, I've tried `$('#my-final-table hr').on("click",function(){alert("foo");});` so I'm trying to bind it after loading data:

```
var jsondata=[
  {
    "band": "Weezer",
    "song": "El Scorcho"
  },
  {
    "band": "Chevelle",
    "song": "Family System"
  }
];
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: jsondata
  }
})
.bind('dynatable:afterProcess', function(){alert('foo')});
```

But it doesn't work, no alert is shown after loading.
JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/pDVvx/

Comment: I don't see any `hr` in your HTML whether it is generated by `dynatable` or Normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example from the dynatable website they manually call the `afterProcess` function the first time it runs. For your code that looks something like:

```
var processingComplete = function(){alert('foo')};
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: jsondata
  }
}).bind('dynatable:afterProcess', processingComplete);

// call the first time manually
processingComplete();
```

If you want to see this in a fiddle, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/pDVvx/2/

In case you were interested the dynatable code I'm referring to is:

```
$table.dynatable({
  // settings & code here
}).bind('dynatable:afterProcess', updateChart);

// Run our updateChart function for the first time.
updateChart();
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

try adding a parameter to your callback function

```
$('#my-final-table').dynatable({
   dataset: {
   records: jsondata
}
}).bind('dynatable:afterUpdate', processingComplete);

function processingComplete(a)
{
 alert('foo');
}
```